# Error loading Jar file with Tomcat 7, Spring 3 and Camel 2.9.1

Tags: spring, exception, tomcat, classloader, apache-camel

I'm getting the following exception while running Camel (2.9.1) on Tomcat (apache-tomcat-7.0.26) with Spring (3.0.5.RELEASE).

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

`Mar 12, 2012 3:03:48 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/Users/XXXX/Documents/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.1.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
[          http-bio-8080-exec-1] ContextLoader                  ERROR Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.BridgeMethodResolver.isVisibilityBridgeMethodPair(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildAutowiringMetadata(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:346)[spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findAutowiringMetadata(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:317)[spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:216)[spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:797)[spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:492)[spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)[spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)[spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)[spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)[spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)[spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:722)[spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)[spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)[spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)[spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)[spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1467)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)[:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)[:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)[:1.6.0_29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)[:1.6.0_29]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)[:1.6.0_29]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1436)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:673)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:431)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)[servlet-api.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)[servlet-api.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)[:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)[:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)[:1.6.0_29]
Mar 12, 2012 3:03:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a version mismatch between your Spring jar files, you are using **spring-web 3.0.5** and **spring-beans 3.0.7**, **spring-context 3.0.7** and .... Use a consistent version of Spring jar files, and your problem shall go.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Maven. Shouldn't Maven take care of that (sorry new to both Maven and Spring.) I've only one Spring version (  <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
) specified in my pom.xml

Comment: I'm not a maven expert, but there must be dependency on Spring 3.0.7 in one of your dependencies, you can make maven to dismiss some library (or dependency).

Comment: So I deleted my local maven cache. Changed spring.version to 3.0.7.RELEASE everywhere in my pom.xml but I still get the same exception. Any ideas ?

Comment: Earlier I had deleted just the maven cache for the springsource folder. This time I deleted everything in maven cache and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you should not have the servlet spec jar in the war. Can you try to make the dependency to the servlet spec of scope provided. That will avoid putting it into the war.