# junit tests fail with NoSuchMethodError BridgeMethodResolver.isVisibilityBridgeMethodPair

Tags: spring, maven, junit

I upgraded my maven project to use Spring 3.0.7 (from 3.0.5). Now, all my junit tests that use the

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

annotation fail (with exception below), but only when running from within Eclipse. I am running "Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2".  Everything passes when I run from linux console.

Anyone come across this before ?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.BridgeMethodResolver.isVisibilityBridgeMethodPair(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)Z
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildAutowiringMetadata(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:346)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findAutowiringMetadata(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:216)
at  
etc & so forth...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved - and it was down to having both 3.0.5 and 3.0.7 JARs on the classpath. I got a clue from this question: [Error loading Jar file with Tomcat 7, Spring 3 and Camel 2.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9673217/156477)

Despite the fact the Eclipse was reporting all spring jar files were 3.0.7, I found that it was hanging onto a reference to an older jar (3.0.5). I found this by deleting all existing spring files from my Maven Repository and rebuilding. I then started getting explicit msgs about a missing $M2_REPO/com/spring...../3.0.5 jar file.